# Expresiones Regulares en Java

Tags: java, regex

necesito por favor a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a extraer de un pdf una usando expresiones regulares en Java el patrón del colegio coomo se muestra en la imagen. 
Actualmente intento extraer de esta manera y no me funciona. Muchas gracias por su ayuda . Atentamente

```
Pattern patCol = Pattern.compile("Centro de Votación: [0-9a-zA-Z]"); 
Matcher matCol = patCol.matcher(cleanpageone);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Escarlet Escoto a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. ¿Que problema has tenido con lo que has intentado? Comparte algún ejemplo real en texto y no en imagen. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En tu regex falta el símbolo +.
Sería así:

```
Centro de Votación: [0-9a-zA-Z]+/gm
```

Te recomiendo usar páginas del estilo de regex101 para testear los regex que vayas haciendo